# Merging log data in python

Tags: python

I have log data in 7 separate files which I need to merge into one file before I can conduct any page analysis on it. Below I have provided an example of a line within one of the log data files

```
207.46.13.124 - - [01/Jun/2015:00:00:04 +0000] "GET /maritime/collections/hmsconway/hiscock/index.aspx HTTP/1.0" 200 "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"
```

The names of the files are `u_ex150601`, `u_ex150602`, `u_ex150603`, `u_ex1506014`, `u_ex150605`, `u_ex150606`, and `u_ex150607`.

How do I merge all of these together using just Python?

Answer (score 3):

I would personally recommend using bash. Something like,

```
cat u_ex15* >> all_logs
```

But in python you can simply use the following:

```
import glob
all_log_filename = 'all_logs'
log_files = glob.glob('u_ex15*')
for filename in log_files:
    with open(filename) as reader:
        with open(all_log_filename, 'a') as writer:
             writer.write(reader.read())
```

**NOTE**: This is the simplest case where your log files aren't that large. If your log files are large, you may want to iterate over each line or chunks so that you don't run into memory issues. The simplest thing you could do is something like:

```
for filename in log_files:
    with open(filename) as reader:
        with open(all_log_filename, 'a') as writer:
            for line in reader:
                writer.write(line)
```